# Are Xcode 3 snapshots incompatible with Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode

I just recently upgraded to Xcode 4 and noticed that I don't see any snapshots from my previous projects made with Xcode 3. Are they not compatible?

Answer (score 0):

They are compatible, but their location may have changed.

Comment: How do I go about locating the former snapshots I created?  When I open a project in Xcode 4 the "Snapshots" menu option is disabled.

Comment: Mine default to: `Users/username/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Screenshots`