# Things to know/do/check before upgrading to XCode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4

What should someone know or do ***before*** they upgrade from XCode 3 to 4? What did you wish someone had told you before you started the install? For example...

[Are Xcode 3 snapshots incompatible with Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314028/are-xcode-3-snapshots-incompatible-with-xcode-4)

[Will I be able to run older applications on the new version of xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511913/upgrading-xcode)

Links are as welcome as original advice, but please don't just search and paste, check it's specifically useful for someone to know *before* they do the new install.

Please note: I'm ***not*** asking for XCode 4 installation instructions, or for guides on using XCode 4 when you know XCode 3.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install Xcode 4 alongside an existing Xcode 3 installation, so you don't really risk anything by installing it.

The thing that kept me using Xcode 3 for quite a while after installing Xcode 4 was that the new integrated Interface Builder can't handle plugins, which are quite common in Mac development (not relevant for iOS stuff though).

The project format is compatible, so you can open any Xcode 3 project in 4 and vice-versa. Xcode 4 adds some additional files, but Xcode 3 just ignores them.

Answer (score 0):

I had not trouble migrating. Just in case, make a backup of all your projects so you can restore them and reinstall Xcode 3 later.

Comment: I believe you can install xcode 3 and 4 side by side. On my system I also have xcode 4 and the new beta release installed I just placed the beta in a new folder called `/DeveloperBeta`

Comment: That usually works, but with every installation of Xcode you are also installing developer tools in the system directory, and only one copy of that can be installed at a time. This is not always an issue, but I had problems when I installed Xcode 4.0 and 4.2 side by side; if I upgraded developer tools in the process, 4.0 stopped working. If I didn't, 4.2 wouldn't work. So I ended up doing a dual boot with 2 copies of Snow Leopard. The Apple docs talk about that somewhere.

Comment: That's odd I did have some issues experimenting but I got them to play nice after a while (uninstalling them both and starting from scratch), but yes you are correct the new tools will wipe out the old ones so there is always some risk. The main thing is how good is your version control/backup procedures because if you are confident they are fine then you should have no worries with experimenting to get things set up right

Answer (score 0):

You should be warned that XCode 4 uses an inordinate amount of memory, to the point making it useless on some systems (even relatively modern ones like my 2010 MacBook 6,1). It also spends an enormous amount of time indexing. Other than that, I have not noticed any problems loading XCode 3 project files into it. I do not use many plugins, so I don't know what the level of backward-compatibility for plugins is like.